# Youtube API v3, how to get video playlist durations?

Tags: video, youtube, google-api

I have tried the method of getting video duration, by this GET [url](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=QoQ_dHCi-08&list=RDUZWrltQLTzE&part=snippet,contentDetails&key=AIzaSyDWlykc0oT692JDUCSwURgRuvt8wGVySGQ&format=json&fields=items(snippet(title),contentDetails(duration)))

and passed this parameters

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?
id=QoQ_dHCi-08&  // video id
list=RDUZWrltQLTzE& // playlist id (TODO from this i want full duration)
part=snippet,contentDetails&
key={MYAPIKEY}&
format=json&
fields=items(snippet(title),contentDetails(duration))
```

after this i am only getting video duration NOT Play List total duration
also seen the method they are using link: http://youtube-playlist-analyzer... 
 [image: i am getting total duration here but i want my own code to get this]  and i just needed to see the playlist total duration by code.
is there any method that i can paas playlist id and get total duration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $result = array();
    function callone($playlistId, $nextpagetoken=''){
        $apikey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
        $dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=".urlencode($playlistId)."&part=snippet&maxResults=50&key=$apikey&pageToken=$nextpagetoken&fields=items(snippet(resourceId(videoId))),nextPageToken");
        $youtubeInfo = json_decode($dur, true);
        $sum=0;
        for($i=0; $i<count($youtubeInfo['items']); $i++){
            $sum++;
            $result[] = $youtubeInfo['items'][$i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
        }
        echo '-'.$sum.'-';
        if(isset($youtubeInfo['nextPageToken'])){
            var_dump($youtubeInfo['nextPageToken']);
            $result = array_merge($result, callone($playlistId, $youtubeInfo['nextPageToken']));

            unset($youtubeInfo['nextPageToken']);
        }
        return $result;
    }

// PLh-evOzpQ6aXxmdYLdHa2VjzkMA9340NO   -> 20 songs
// PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj   -> 176 songs

 $mani = callone('PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj'); // playlistId with 176 songs
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($mani);
?>
```